# remove rows from a dataframe based on date of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. One column called Date contains a list of dates.

Say the dates range from 1st Jan 2015 to 1st Jan 2019.

I want to remove all rows where the Date is less than the 1st March 2018.

Below are the things I have tried without any luck.

```
dc = urv['Date'] >= pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 1)
urv.drop(dc=False)


urv.drop(urv['Date'] >= pd.Timestamp(2018, 3, 1))
```

Comment: can we get a mcve?

Comment: sorry whats an mcve? I'm new to python

Comment: a [minimal&reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, also ceck this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Try `urv[urv['Date'] >= '2018-03-01']` and if necessary before `urv['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(urv['Date'])`